# wildfly 8.2.0 oracle datasource

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, wildfly-8

i have some problem with oracle datasource in wildfly 8.2.0 server. I use server in domain mode with two server and domain controller with default profile. So in my domain.xml is declared datasource and drivers

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/mur-ng-mur" pool-name="mur-ng-mur" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip</connection-url>
                    <driver>oracle</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>name</user-name>
                        <password>pass</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                      <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
                      <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"></stale-connection-checker>
                      <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"></exception-sorter>
                    </validation>
                    <timeout>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>30</idle-timeout-minutes>
                    </timeout>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc7">
                        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
```

of corse i defined module oracle in /server/wildfly-8.2.0-final/modules

server started correctly and in web console appear new oracle datasource. I try "test conncetion" it was successfully.

And then in my code defined

```
@Resource(name = "java:jboss/datasources/mur-ng-mur")
private javax.sql.DataSource myDB;


try {
        LOGGER.debug("myDB: " + myDB.getConnection());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error("error db get connection: ", e);
}
```

myDB.getConnection()
throw exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@53412941[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@10a8e4c5 connection handles=0 lastUse=1449678786540 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@3ded1c50 mcp=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@12715602[pool=ExampleDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@50beb6d1[connectionListener=53412941 connectionManager=42e39007 warned=false currentXid=null productName=H2 productVersion=1.3.173 (2013-07-28) jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS] txSync=null]
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:154) ~[na:na]
at sk.posam.risng.mur.bpm.beans.uzavierka.UzavierkaProcess.spustiVytvorenieUzavierky(UzavierkaProcess.java:42) ~[classes:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor260.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:479) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.el.AbstractElResolverDelegate.invoke(AbstractElResolverDelegate.java:93) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:397) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.juel.AstMethod.invoke(AstMethod.java:91) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.juel.AstMethod.eval(AstMethod.java:75) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.juel.AstEval.eval(AstEval.java:50) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.juel.AstNode.getValue(AstNode.java:26) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.juel.TreeValueExpression.getValue(TreeValueExpression.java:114) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.delegate.ExpressionGetInvocation.invoke(ExpressionGetInvocation.java:33) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.delegate.DelegateInvocation.proceed(DelegateInvocation.java:39) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.delegate.DefaultDelegateInterceptor.handleInvocation(DefaultDelegateInterceptor.java:59) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.el.JuelExpression.getValue(JuelExpression.java:50) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ServiceTaskExpressionActivityBehavior.execute(ServiceTaskExpressionActivityBehavior.java:44) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:42) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:27) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:134) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:494) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:484) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:464) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.eventNotificationsCompleted(PvmAtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.java:56) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.eventNotificationsCompleted(PvmAtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.java:26) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:65) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:134) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:494) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:473) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:58) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:134) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:494) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:473) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:58) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:134) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:494) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:473) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:58) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:134) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:494) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:484) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:464) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.scopeCreated(PvmAtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.java:34) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationCreateScope.execute(PvmAtomicOperationCreateScope.java:50) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationCreateScope.execute(PvmAtomicOperationCreateScope.java:24) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:134) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext$1.call(CommandContext.java:122) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext$1.call(CommandContext.java:120) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.context.ProcessApplicationClassloaderInterceptor.call(ProcessApplicationClassloaderInterceptor.java:44) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.application.impl.EjbProcessApplication.execute(EjbProcessApplication.java:133) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor232.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar!/:2014-10-03 10:05]
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:52) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:251) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:342) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:448) [wildfly-security-manager-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar!/:1.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
at org.camunda.bpm.application.ProcessApplicationInterface$$$view2.execute(Unknown Source) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.context.Context.executeWithinProcessApplication(Context.java:193) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:120) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.AsyncContinuationJobHandler.execute(AsyncContinuationJobHandler.java:90) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.JobEntity.execute(JobEntity.java:123) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.ExecuteJobsCmd.execute(ExecuteJobsCmd.java:100) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:24) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:97) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.JtaTransactionInterceptor.execute(JtaTransactionInterceptor.java:59) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:32) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.ExecuteJobsRunnable.executeJob(ExecuteJobsRunnable.java:79) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.ExecuteJobsRunnable.run(ExecuteJobsRunnable.java:67) [camunda-engine-7.3.0.jar!/:7.3.0]
at org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(SimpleDirectExecutor.java:33) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar!/:2.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(QueueExecutor.java:808) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar!/:2.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(QueueExecutor.java:45) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar!/:2.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run(QueueExecutor.java:849) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar!/:2.1.1.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar!/:2.1.1.Final]
```

Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@53412941[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@10a8e4c5 connection handles=0 lastUse=1449678786540 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@3ded1c50 mcp=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@12715602[pool=ExampleDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@50beb6d1[connectionListener=53412941 connectionManager=42e39007 warned=false currentXid=null productName=H2 productVersion=1.3.173 (2013-07-28) jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS] txSync=null]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:780) ~[na:na]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:518) ~[na:na]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146) ~[na:na]
    ... 132 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000461: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:551) ~[na:na]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:775) ~[na:na]
    ... 134 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: IJ000356: Failed to enlist: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings. tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffac100214:-17c76a7:566855c8:395 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener$TransactionSynchronization.checkEnlisted(TxConnectionListener.java:848) ~[na:na]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:383) ~[na:na]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:544) ~[na:na]
    ... 135 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch Datasource like this . I assume that You are using this in some @Stateless bean

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    String datasourceName = "java:jboss/datasources/mur-ng-mur";
    Context ctx;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext();
        dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(datasourceName);
        LOG.info("Datasource {} initialized", datasourceName);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        LOG.error("ERROR reading datasource for name={}", datasourceName, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception talks about "jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS".
Your problem must to be in another place of your code. Try to search for ExampleDS first in your project.